# How do clear: left and clear: right work?

Tags: html, css

I know that the `clear: both` property is used to clear floated elements. What about `clear: left` and `clear: right`? How and when do I use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those values tell a box to clear only left floats or only right floats respectively. Instead of stacking horizontally to either a left float's right, or a right float's left, it will stack *beneath* the float respectively.

If you have a series of left and right floated elements, `clear: left` clears a box only from previous boxes that were floated left, and `clear: right` clears it only from previous boxes that were floated right.

If the boxes before a `clear: left` box are floated right, the box itself will float right as well, as it has not cleared the right floats. Likewise when a `clear: right` follows boxes that are only floated to the left, the box itself will float left as well.

Some visual explanations:

- [SitePoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/floatclear)
- [W3C CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2.1/visuren.html#propdef-clear)